# Magento AddToCart after place order due to delay in response

Tags: magento2, rest-api, mobile

We have recently faced strange issue related to an specific order placed from iOS. We are using flutter and utilizing Magento restAPI. There is an order having grand total of 379 but the amount sent to payment method is 209 just for three product. The last item price is not added into the total before the request made. As per current scenario due to some delay the item added after placing the order or somewhat else. Now I have 2 questions.

1. How to restrict user to break the session right away after placing the order so If someone using same account in another mobile he/she can use separate session.
2. If someone moved to checkout how to lock the current quote